# Cross checking *multiple* vectors against each other to test whether all elements exist in all vectors

Tags: r, vector

I have multiple sets (vectors) that must include the same elements. 
In theory they should, but in reality, I'm being suspicious that 
some vectors are missing some elements.

All the methods that I've seen for that kind of a problem address a 2-vector situation, but aren't applicable when having multiple vectors.

In short, what I'm looking for is applying `setequal()` for multiple vectors, since neither uniqueness nor order matter to me.

Here's an example:

```
#Six sets of characters&numbers that are pretty similar, though not identical
vec_a <- unlist(strsplit("Z d 5 A P y 4 R 6 y w u N T b", split=" "))
vec_b <- unlist(strsplit("Z d 5 B P y 4 R 6 y w u N T b", split=" "))
vec_c <- unlist(strsplit("Z d 5 A P y 4 R 6 y w u N T b", split=" "))
vec_d <- unlist(strsplit("Z d 5 A P x 4 R 6 y w u N W b", split=" "))
vec_e <- unlist(strsplit("Z d 5 A P y 4 R 6 y w u N T b", split=" "))
vec_f <- unlist(strsplit("Z d 5 A P y 4 R 6 y w u N T b", split=" "))

#I want to cross check all 6 sets against each other, 
#to see whether all elements appear in all sets (order doesn't matter, nor uniquness), 
#OR whether some elements DON'T exist in some of the sets. I'd like
#to flag the elements that don't appear in all 6 sets.


#As a start, I just want to get a TRUE/FALSE answer to whether
#all elements appear in all 6 vectors.
Reduce(setequal, list(vec_a, vec_b, vec_c, vec_d, vec_e, vec_f))
[1] FALSE

#It DOES make sense to get that FALSE returned, because 
#not all 6 vectors are the same. 
#HOWEVER, note that vec_a, vec_e, and vec_f ARE IDENTICAL, 
#but when running the following command, I still get FALSE, which doesn't make sense.
Reduce(setequal, list(vec_a, vec_e, vec_f))
[1] FALSE
#So this method clearly doesn't work accurately.
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find all *common* elements with:

```r
l <- list(vec_a, vec_b, vec_c, vec_d, vec_e, vec_f)
( common <- Reduce(intersect, l) )
#  [1] "Z" "d" "5" "P" "y" "4" "R" "6" "w" "u" "N" "b"
```

(Which brings to mind that you might want these stored in a `list` to begin with, not individual vectors, but that as always depends on your over-arching project/application.)

To find what each vector has that is different from this common list:

```r
lapply(l, setdiff, common)
# [[1]]
# [1] "A" "T"
# [[2]]
# [1] "B" "T"
# [[3]]
# [1] "A" "T"
# [[4]]
# [1] "A" "x" "W"
# [[5]]
# [1] "A" "T"
# [[6]]
# [1] "A" "T"
```

(In this example, it would be nicer if the elements of the `list` were named so you'd know which was which ... so you might want to address that in how you generate the `l` list.)

You can find which pairs are identical with:

```r
outer(seq_along(l), seq_along(l),
      function(a,b) mapply(function(A,B) identical(l[[A]], l[[B]]), a, b))
#       [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]  [,6]
# [1,]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
# [2,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# [3,]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
# [4,] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
# [5,]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
# [6,]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```